# Why does initializing C local character arrays internally store the strings in different stack/data segments?

Tags: c, shellcode

While working on some [position-independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code) C injected shellcode, the strings were initially coded using this array initialization

```
char winexec[] = "WinExec";
```

However, this caused the shellcode to fail because the string `WinExec` was stored in the data segment of the injector but the injectee did not have access to that data.

To fix, the array initialization was changed to

```
char winexec[] = { 'W','i','n','E','x','e','c','\0' };
```

which worked perfectly because the string was stored in the injectee local stack segment.

For example https://godbolt.org/z/v8cqn5E56

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    /* String stored in the stack segment */
    char winexecStack[] = { 'W','i','n','E','x','e','c','\0' };

    /* String stored in the data segment */
    char winexecData[] = "WinExec";
    
    printf("Stack Segment: %s\n", winexecStack);
    printf("Data Segment:  %s\n", winexecData);     
    
    return 0;
}
```

**Question**

Why does C have multiple ways to initialize local arrays which externally appear the same, but internally the strings are stored very differently?

Do tidier methods exist to initialize a C character array on the stack?
Maybe something like

```
char winexecStack[8];
winexecStack[0] = 'W';
winexecStack[1] = 'i';
winexecStack[2] = 'n';
winexecStack[3] = 'E';
winexecStack[4] = 'x';
winexecStack[5] = 'e';
winexecStack[6] = 'c';
winexecStack[7] = '\0';
```

or convert strings such as `Hello, World!` to little endian values in an array

```
unsigned long long hello[] = { 0x57202C6F6C6C6548,0x00000021646C726F };
printf("Stack Segment: %s\n", (char*)&hello);
```

Perhaps for strings <= 8 bytes, they could be represented as a numerical value, stored on the stack but treated as a char* for example "WinExec"

```
unsigned long long winexec = 0x00636578456e6957;
printf("Stack Segment: %s\n", (char*)&winexec);
```

Comment: String literals are special - they are defined by the Standard to be have static storage duration. In your second snippet, you have an 'ordinary' array, with automatic duration.

Comment: ... furthermore, although you are using the string literal to initialize an *automatic* array, if that array is never modified after its initialization, I guess the compiler is allowed to optimize it 'away' and just use the literal itself. I think.

Comment: Yes, @AdrianMole, but either way, the data for the initializer have to be stored somewhere in the binary, and in memory at runtime.

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yeah. There's a lot of things here that are quite 'fuzzy'. Which is why I didn't want to post anything quoting the Standard as an answer.

Comment: The godbolt site lets you change the compiler easily. Try "clang" to see the same functionality implemented in a different way (not sure it would break your shellcode).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why does C have multiple ways to initialize local arrays which externally appear the same, but internally the strings are stored very differently?

It doesn't.  That you observe the source data for the initializers to be stored differently in the two cases is a function of your C implementation.  It is not required by the C language itself.  More generally, C has a lot to say about *what* is stored, but less to say about *how* it is stored, and almost nothing to say about *where* it is stored.

> Do tidier methods exist to initialize a C character array on the stack?

A valid character array initializer takes one of the two forms you show.

Note also that "on the stack" is not a C concept (refer to "almost nothing to say about *where*").

Answer (score 1):

Turning on optimization with `/O2` makes the difference vanish. This suggests that, without optimization, the compiler implements C somewhat  literally, putting the array induced by a string literal in a data segment (for static storage) while individual character initializers are treated as small constants. With optimization turned on, the compiler performs deeper semantic analysis and optimizes the generated code, and in fact the constant proposed in the question, 0x00636578456e6957, is seen in the generated assembly.